# While using woocommerce_process_product_meta hook how to debug?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I need to store informations in a custom product type.
I correctly created the form, and I'm using the hook `woocommerce_process_product_meta` to save the custom informations about this product. 
In the same function, I am doing a file upload, like this. The basic informations are saved, but the upload does not work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_my_custom_settings' );
function save_my_custom_settings( $post_id ){
echo "test";
//Save options
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_option', esc_attr( $_POST[ 'my_custom_option' ] ) );

    /*
    * Upload the file
    */
    if ( $_FILES["my_file"] ) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo( $_FILES["my_file"]["name"] );
        $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
        $stored_file_name = time() . '.' . $extension;

        $storage_dir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/downloads';

        $target_file = $storage_dir . '/' . $stored_file_name;

        if ( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) ) {

            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        } else echo "File transfer ok";

        /*
         * Store information on the file
        */  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_file_name', $stored_file_name );
    } else echo "File missing!!";
}
```

I know the directory exists and that the function is called, since the other options are correctly saved. However, the file simply isn't uploaded. 
I'm sure I could debug this myself, the problem is that I don't know how to display any notifications, so I don't know what is wrong. As you can see, in the sample above I tried to use an "echo", but I can't see that output.
What can I use to display a notification when the product is saved, so I know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug in Wordpress you should **first read** the following: [Debugging in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Also read: [Debugging WooCommerce PHP with Javascript console.log doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/debugging-woocommerce-php-with-javascript-console-log-doesnt-work/61754061#61754061)

> Now there is multiple tricks/ways to get the data. I use this sometimes like in your case: 
>   For example you can use some **temporary meta fields** to store any debug data for the current order, with Wordpress function `update_post_meta()`.
>   Then you will be able to output related data with `get_post_meta()` or look directly in database in `wp_postmeta` table for your temporary debug custom fields keys…

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the answer, but your if statement has  `$_FILES["my__file"]` but the other lines have `$_FILES["my_file"]` so there's a discrepancy in the naming there!

Comment: That wasn't it, but thanks for pointing it out, I fixed the question