# How to debug in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, woocommerce

I am creating a custom shipping method for Woocommerce using this tutorial https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/ but I am having issues debugging. Whenever shipping methods get updated by user, Woocommerce calls calculate shipping. I have overridden this function with the following.

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    // This is where you'll add your rates
    $rate = array(
      'idea' => $this->id,
      'label' => $this->title,
      'cost' => '90.00',
      'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
    );
    echo "<script>console.log('Calculating shipping');</script>";
    $this->add_rate($rate);
  }
```

In the end I have a fairly complex way of calculating the "cost" but I have no way of debugging it because that echo line produces no output in the chrome console. Any ideas what is going on here?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> As this is a **background process on server side, don't use javascript**.

#### 1). **WC Logs and the [`WC_Logger` Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-logger.php) in WooCommerce for better debugging**

To access the results of the log easily from the dashboard, **you can log to a WC logger** rather than the error log.

You can access error logs by going to WooCommerce > System Status > Logs.

Then you will be able to choose  and "view"the error log file you need, giving you the debugging details that you need. Error logs are also located in the /wc-logs folder within your site install.

Running a stack trace on a caught exception (example):

```
// Log any exceptions to a WC logger
$log = new WC_Logger();
$log_entry = print_r( $e, true );
$log_entry .= 'Exception Trace: ' . print_r( $e->getTraceAsString(), true );
$log->log( 'new-woocommerce-log-name', $log_entry );
```

> #### **Notes:**
>
> - [`WC_Logger` methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-logger.php) have been updated since WooCommerce 3: **So logging can be grouped by context and severity.**
> - Use [`WC_Logger` `log()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.1/includes/class-wc-logger.php#L95-L118) instead of [`add()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.1/includes/class-wc-logger.php#L120-L149)  due to [**upcoming deprecation**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.1/includes/class-wc-logger.php#L98-L99) *(thanks to [@Vizz85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5956354/vizz85))*.

For example:

```
$logger = wc_get_logger();
$logger->debug( 'debug message', array( 'source' => 'my-extension' ) );
```

Related:

- Develop WooCommerce blog *(january 2017)*: [Improved logging in WooCommerce 3](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/improved-logging-in-woocommerce-2-7/)
- Documentation on the [`WC_Logger` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Logger.html)

---

#### 2). **Debugging with WordPress `WP_DEBUG` Log** *(as an alternative)*

a) First edit your `wp-config.php` file adding the following lines to enable debug (if these are already defined, edit the values):

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

As errors are logged, they should appear in `wp-content/debug.log`. You can open this file in a text editor.

b) On your code: Use the following (where `$variable` is the variable to be displayed in the error log:

```
error_log( print_r( $variable, true ) );
```

Now you will get the data for debugging.

Comment: This worked but other developers on my team are outputting so much junk to out debug.log it is almost impossible to find the output from my plugin. I figured I could just write to a .txt file but this isn't working either. I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure of the rules. Is this something I should create a new question for?

Comment: @DallinDavis I have updated my answer… There is `WC_Logger`  special Class in WooCommerce that is super useful for debugging... see above.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that `WC_Logger::log` should be preferred over `WC_Logger::add` due to possible future deprecation: [WooCommerce docs](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_loggeradd/)

Comment: @Vizz85 yes you are completely right… I updated my answer and  added a small note crediting you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First Creat PHP helper function

```
 function console_output($data) {
 $output = $data;
if (is_array($output))
    $output = implode(',', $output);

  echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
 }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
// This is where you'll add your rates
$rate = array(
  'idea' => $this->id,
  'label' => $this->title,
  'cost' => '90.00',
  'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
     );
   console_output("Calculating shipping");
    $this->add_rate($rate);
   }
```

This will create an output like this:

```
  Debug Objects: Calculating shipping
```