# How to check the value of a WooCommerce filter hook parameter?

Tags: php, woocommerce, parameters, hook-woocommerce, error-log

In WooCommerce you have many hooks & filters. How can I check what is inside of a filter parameter? For example, I want to unset some shipping rates based on certain conditions. How can I check what is inside my $rates or $package parameter?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wbgoe_shipping_rates', 20, 2);

function wbgoe_shipping_rates($rates, $package) {
    print_r($rates); \\ How to check what's inside of $rates??
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first enable Wordpress debug log by editing your `wp-config.php` file adding the following lines to enable debug (if these are already defined, edit the values):

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Now you can use `error_log()` function in your code as follows:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'check_shipping_rates', 20, 2);

function check_shipping_rates($rates, $package) {
    error_log( print_r( $rates, true ) );
    return $rates;
}
```

As errors are logged, they should appear in wp-content/debug.log. You can open this file in a text editor. Once you have finished, you can disable debug log.

Related: [How to debug in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/how-to-debug-in-woocommerce-3/61754061#61754061)