# Display shipping method costs on single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

So I'm trying to output the delivery methods based on shipping class and show their price, delivery time.

I managed to come up to a point where everything is pretty much working, but the price is not being updated correctly. It always shows 0,00 even price is set to 3,50.

I could put it directly into code, but I want to get it updated from WooCommerce delivery settings.

```php
function display_shipping_methods() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->needs_shipping()) {
        $output = '<div class="shipping-methods">';
        $output .= '<h5>Galimi pristatymo būdai:</h5>';
        $output .= '<ul>';

        // Check the product's shipping class slug
        $product_shipping_class = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_shipping_class');
        $product_shipping_class_slug = !empty($product_shipping_class) ? esc_html($product_shipping_class[0]->slug) : '';

        if ($product_shipping_class_slug === '1') {
            // If the product's shipping class slug is '1', allow specific delivery methods
            $allowed_shipping_methods = array(
                'Atsiėmimas vietoje' => '2-4 dienos',
                'Omniva (Lithuania) Paštomatai' => '1-3 dienos',
                'LP Express Paštomatai' => '1-3 dienos',
            );

            $shipping_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
            foreach ($shipping_zones as $shipping_zone) {
                $shipping_methods = $shipping_zone['shipping_methods'];

                foreach ($shipping_methods as $method) {
                    $method_title = esc_html($method->get_title());
                    $method_id = $method->instance_id; // Get the method ID

                    // Check if the method title matches exactly with allowed methods
                    if (array_key_exists($method_title, $allowed_shipping_methods)) {
                        $method_class = sanitize_title($method_title);

                        // Get the cost for the method dynamically based on its ID
                        $method_cost = get_option("woocommerce_flat_rate_{$method_id}_cost");
                        $delivery_time = $allowed_shipping_methods[$method_title];

                        $output .= '<li class="' . $method_class . '">';
                        $output .= '<span class="method-icon"></span>';
                        $output .= esc_html($method_title);
                        $output .= ' - Price: ' . wc_price($method_cost);
                        $output .= ' - Delivery Time: ' . esc_html($delivery_time);
                        $output .= '</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}

add_shortcode('shipping_methods', 'display_shipping_methods');
```

To make delivery methods and their details show in single product page.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake when trying to get the shipping cost from shipping settings and some unnecessary complications.

Also, to get the correct cost depending on the settings costs, you need to check first if there is a cost set for the product shipping class…

Try the following:

```php
function display_shipping_methods() {
    global $product;

    $targeted_shipping_class = '1'; // The targeted shipping class slug

    // check that the product has the correct shipping class slug
    if ( $product->needs_shipping() && $product->get_shipping_class() == $targeted_shipping_class ) {
        // Array of allowed shipping methods with their delivery time
        $allowed_shipping_methods = array(
            'Atsiėmimas vietoje' => '2-4 dienos',
            'Omniva (Lithuania) Paštomatai' => '1-3 dienos',
            'LP Express Paštomatai' => '1-3 dienos',
        );

        $output = '<div class="shipping-methods">
        <h5>' . __("Galimi pristatymo būdai:") . '</h5><ul>';

        // Loop thhrough shipping zones
        foreach ( WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones() as $shipping_zone ) {

            // Loop through shipping methods for the current shipping zone
            foreach ( $shipping_zone['shipping_methods'] as $method ) {
                $method_title = esc_html($method->get_title());
                $method_id = $method->get_instance_id(); // Get the method ID

                // Check if the method title matches exactly with allowed methods
                if ( array_key_exists( $method_title, $allowed_shipping_methods ) ) {
                    $method_class  = sanitize_title($method_title);
                    $delivery_time = $allowed_shipping_methods[$method_title];

                    $output .= '<li class="' . $method_class . '">
                    <span class="method-icon"></span>' . esc_html($method_title);

                    // Get the shipping settings from database
                    $method_settings = get_option( "woocommerce_flat_rate_{$method_id}_settings" );
                    $class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Get the product shipping class ID

                    // Check if the cost is set for the product shipping class ID
                    if ( isset($method_settings["class_cost_{$class_id}"]) && ! empty($method_settings["class_cost_{$class_id}"]) ) {
                        $output .= ' - Price: ' . wc_price($method_settings["class_cost_{$class_id}"]);
                    }
                    // else check if the cost is set for the product with NO shipping class ID
                    elseif ( isset($method_settings["no_class_cost"]) && ! empty($method_settings["no_class_cost"]) ) {
                        $output .= ' - Price: ' . wc_price($method_settings["no_class_cost"]);
                    }
                    // else check if there is a normal cost
                    elseif ( isset($method_settings['cost']) && ! empty($method_settings['cost']) ) {
                        $output .= ' - Price: ' . wc_price($method_settings['cost']);
                    }
                    $output .= ' - Delivery Time: ' . esc_html($delivery_time) . '</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $output . '</ul></div>';
    }
}

add_shortcode('shipping_methods', 'display_shipping_methods');
```

It should work

Comment: appreciate for the help.  However now it looks like the 'price' is not being output too. Just goes like : Atsiėmimas vietoje -Delivery Time: 2-4 dienos

Comment: You need to enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`as explained [**in here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754061/3730754)… Then add below the first occurrence of `$method_settings` the following line `error_log(print_r($method_settings, true));`. Browse the product page and look to the error log file. You should get all settings data array for each shipping method. Then you will be able to make the require changes in the code to get the cost display... In my case, I have tested the code and it works.