# Woocommerce Booking doesn't work in some products and all the plugins and theme were updated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, woocommerce-bookings

I have a website for a travel agency, and I use the Woocommerce Booking plugin for tour reservations. However, I've noticed that on certain products. What makes this issue particularly challenging to diagnose is that it occurs randomly across different products, making it difficult to identify a consistent pattern. The calendar simply gets stuck loading indefinitely.
Interestingly, every time I make a change to the website, the issue resolves itself.

I builded the website with elementor and elementor pro. This are the plugins I'm actually using Elementor
Elementor Pro
Elements kit lite
Envato
LiteSpeed Cache
Select Primary Addon for Elementor
Primary Addon for Elementor
Simple History
WooCommerce
WooCommerce Checkout Manager
WooCommerce Google Analytics Integration
WP Headers And Footers
WP Mail SMTP
WP Statistics
WPForms Lite

The hosting provider is Hostinger.

I've attempted troubleshooting by clearing the cache and deactivating various plugins to check if any of them might be conflicting with Woocommerce Booking. Nevertheless, it's worth noting that each time I make a modification to the website, the problem seems to spontaneously correct itself.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to JavaScript / Ajax… When the problem occurs, check your browser console.  You should also [enable WP_DEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754061/3730754) temporarily…