# WooCommerce custom PDF plugin issue with order and order item data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, orders

For my WooCommerce store, I am writing a plugin that when an item is placed, creates a PDF with a picking list and a delivery label.  It all works, except I can not seem to get the items in the order, I can get the order status and other parts of the order just not the items.

```
    // Getting an instance of the WC_Order object from a defined ORDER ID
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Iterating through each "line" items in the order
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
    $product        = $item->get_product();
    $product_name   = $item->get_name(); // Get the item name (product name)
    $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity


    // Add item name and quantity to the PDF (Picking List)
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.'", 0, 1);
}
```

I have tried pushing the items to the debugging log, but it isn't showing the details of the items, and so I think it is the way I am getting the items, rather than an error with writing them to the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be sure that you are getting the right Order ID, as without that nothing works (just as you describe).

Try to enable `WP_DEBUG` as explained in [How to debug in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/how-to-debug-in-woocommerce-3/61754061#61754061) answer.

Then insert just before `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` the following *(temporary, for debug)*:

```php
error_log( 'Order_id: ' . $order_id ); // Display the order ID in the debug.log file

if ( ! ( $order_id && $order_id > 0 ) ) {
    return; // Exit if not a numerical order ID greater than 0
}
```

Then when you are sure that you have the correct order ID related to the order, you can remove the debug code, and disable `WP_DEBUG`.

---

Now, there is a little mistake in the last code line *(double quotes with single quotes string concatenation issue)*:

```php
// Add item name and quantity to the PDF (Picking List)
  $pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.'", 0, 1);
```

Need to be replaced with:

```php
// Add item name and quantity to the PDF (Picking List)
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Product name: {$product_name} | Quantity: {$item_quantity}", 0, 1);
```

or with:

```php
// Add item name and quantity to the PDF (Picking List)
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Product name: ".$product_name." | Quantity: ".$item_quantity, 0, 1);
```

It should work.

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Thanks, so i know i am getting the correct order number, as i already display the order number , the order status etc. in the pdf just to show me that i am pulling the correct information.  I have tried all of your suggestions, but nothing, works, i am also not getting any errors.  I have tried striping back all of the plugins that aren't necessary, but still nothing.

Comment: The order number can be different from the order ID, so you need to be sure that you get the order ID.

Comment: Sorry, long day i meant the order, Id, i also get order status, customer id, date created, date modified and any other information, it just doesn't return anything to do with the items.  I have removed plugins, changed the theme, it just doesn't provide the information.  I have even tried it on two different servers.