# Check changes from WooCommerce version 8.2.2 to 8.3.1

Tags: woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce, versioning, woocommerce-theming

Recently our plugin faces some issues on WooCommerce version 8.3.1, but it is working properly now. We have decreased the WooCommerce version to 8.2.2 and resolve the old errors, but now new problems arrived basically we are working with the product price and cart price is there any way to know that WooCommerce have changed their hooks from version 8.2.2. to 8.3.1. I just want to know the changes, it will help me to identify the problem exact location.

I also have found this issue: [WooCommerce Support » Checkout broke with 8.3.0](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/checkout-broke-with-8-3-0/)

Comment: [See WooCommerce changelog for all versions](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/trunk/changelog.txt) and [all the remaining known issues](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues)… Also, you should enable `WP_DEBUG` as explained [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754061/3730754), to better identify your plugin issues to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the forum page linked a use named kevin said

I have found the problem.
In

```
/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php
```

In

```
static_function_register_script
```

and

```
static_function_enqueue_script
```

the last parameter

```
$in_footer
```

was changed from

```
`$in_footer = true`
```

to

```
$in_footer = array ( ‘strategy’ => ‘defer’)
```

Changing this back to true, checkout works again.

Here is the commit that broke this functionality: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/fe6e43b438710ecd3b0a97bfbe74bc6559a3db69

Kevin

could not tell you if this will fix or not, so please don't take my word as law, just something to try maybe