# How to add additional fee for specific payment method on checkout page with Woocommerce Gutenberg block?

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, gutenberg-blocks, fee

When the checkout page is generated by 'woocommerce_checkout' shortcode, we can use 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' hook to add an additional fee for any specific payment method with this js code to add the fee and change the total amount.

```
$("body").trigger("update_checkout");
```

But if the checkout page is generated by Woocommerce Gutenberg block, this code doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you need to embed it like [in this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642297/3730754), making sure that `input[name=payment_method]` match with the generated payment fields HTML "name" attribute… and change `woocommerce_checkout_init` hook with for example `wp_head` hook targeting your custom checkout page.

Comment: The answer you have mentioned does not work for the Woocommerce Gutenberg checkout block. The input field’s on-change event works fine, but the problem is with the ‘update_checkout’ event, which doesn’t trigger. 
`$("body").trigger("update_checkout");`

Comment: You need to check what are the available jQuery events delegated to the document.body in your custom checkout page… maybe the related event to be triggered has a different name or maybe it doesn't exist any for Gutenberg checkout block…